# How to display Image reference above even I isolate certain object?

Tags: modeling, customization

As I know Blender 2.79 can display refence image even during isolating an object. I use 2.83.8 version and can't find right option. I tired to select all images and an object and isolate them every time. Is there an option? Thank you!

Comment: Hello :). By isolating you mean *Local View*?

Comment: yes, by Slash key

Answer (score 1):

Works just fine for me.
Make sure you selected all objects you need isolated.

[image]

Comment: _I tired to select all images and an object and isolate them every time_